# Why does std::stol not work with scientific notation?

Tags: c++

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    long l1 = std::stol("4.2e+7");
    long l2 = std::stol("3E+7");
    long l3 = 3E7;
    printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n", l1, l2, l3);

    return 0;
}
```

The expected output is `42000000, 3000000, 3000000` but the actual output is (tested on ideone C++14 and VS2013):

```
4
3
30000000
```

Why is this and is there anyway to make `std::stol` take into account scientific notation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function you are looking for is `std::stof` and not `std::stol`. `std::stof` calls `std::strtod` under the hood, which supports scientific notation. However, `std::stol` calls `std::strtol` under the hood, which doesn't.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    long l1 = std::stof("4.2e+7");
    long l2 = std::stof("3E+7");
    long l3 = 3E7;
    std::cout << l1 << "\n" << l2 << "\n" << l3;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
42000000
30000000
30000000
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI for anyone else stumbling upon this solution, a more robust way of reading in a string containing a number with scientific notation for an exponent would be to use `std::stringstream`, [as documented in the *C++ Cookbook*](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/c-cookbook/0596007612/ch03s06.html) and in this StackOverflow question (["String to float using stringstream"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947607/string-to-float-using-stringstream))

Effectively, like this:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

   std::string number = "1.0E+6";
   std::stringstream ss(str);
   double d = 0;
   ss >> d; // d = 1.0E6
```